# how to parse this json file without array name and object name?

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

I want to parse this json but this json have no array name or no object name. i need to get id,color,description.

```
[
    {
        "id": "mLPjQs-YK5g",
        "created_at": "2018-06-20T02:06:38-04:00",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-20T10:56:38-04:00",
        "width": 4016,
        "height": 6016,
        "color": "#D7A694",
        "description": null
    },
    {
        "id": "HcgDLkDbo7U",
        "created_at": "2018-06-20T10:15:12-04:00",
        "updated_at": "2018-06-20T10:54:30-04:00",
        "width": 3648,
        "height": 5472,
        "color": "#E1D6DE",
        "description": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Check if your "dates" array is null before setting it in the adapter.

Comment: The array could be empty but not null. Setting a null array will throw a Null pointer exception.